# Why did my program have no results?The a is definitely 625

Tags: java

```
package com.wukang.demo;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 11; i < 32;i++) {
            int a = i * i;
            int b = i & 10;
            int c = i / 10;
            if((a / 10 & 10) == c && (a & 10 ) == b ) {
                System.out.println(a);                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm, what your program should do? it is unclear what your program do?, can u you explain more?

Comment: Did you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Your program had no results because the if condition isn't fulfilled. I don't know what that statement is supposed to do, but it's a great reason to not combine so many conditions on a single line.

Comment: Hmm, probably because your if condition is never evaluating to true?! Seriously: if your program doesn't behave as expected, simply use a debugger, or much easier: add **print** statements all along the way. You could simply print all those intermediate results; and then see why your condition is never met.

Comment: If you add the else condition in your program it will always execute the else block as your code is not fulfilling if condition.

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i = 11; i < 32;i++) {
                int a = i * i;
                int b = i & 10;
                int c = i / 10;
                if((a / 10 & 10) == c && (a & 10 ) == b ) {
                    System.out.println(a);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("error" );
                }
            }
        }

Try this code and debug you will find your mistake

Comment: I used & instead of %.Haha......@AmitGujarathi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 11; i < 32; i++) {
    int a = i * i;
    int b = i % 10;
    int c = i / 10;
    if ((a / 10 % 10) == c && (a % 10) == b) {
    //---------------------------^
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**You used & instead of %**

Comment: How did you know/guess that he meant to do a modulo? I call black magic haxx! ;)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS sometimes I make this mistake too  %=(shift+5) &=(shift+6) on keyboard - and it was pure luck modulo brings the expected result ^^

Comment: I didn't expect that I made this mistake, thank you!@Kidded @YCF_L

Comment: @K.J you have to mark this answer like an accepted one read this for more informations https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @YCF_L This is my first time to ask questions, there are many aspects do not understand, thank you advise！